# Python Joining List and adding and removing characters

Tags: python

I have a list i need to .join as string and append characters

```
my_list = ['3.3.3.3', '2.2.2.3', '2.2.2.2']

my_list.append(')"')
my_list.insert(0,'"(')

hostman = '|'.join('{0}'.format(w) for w in my_list)

#my_list.pop()
print(hostman)
print(my_list)
```

My output = "(|3.3.3.3|2.2.2.3|2.2.2.2|)"

I need the output to be = "(3.3.3.3|2.2.2.3|2.2.2.2)"

how can i strip the first and last | from the string

Answer (score 2):

You are making it harder than it needs to be. You can just use `join()` directly with the list:

```
my_list = ['3.3.3.3', '2.2.2.3', '2.2.2.2']
s = '"(' + '|'.join(my_list) + ')"'

# s is "(3.3.3.3|2.2.2.3|2.2.2.2)"
# with quotes as part of the string
```

or if you prefer `format`:

```
s = '"({})"'.format('|'.join(my_list))
```

Comment: Good answer for a classic XY problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i'm only getting (3.3.3.3|2.2.2.3|2.2.2.2)

Comment: i need it to be "(3.3.3.3|2.2.2.3|2.2.2.2)" with the start and ending " as i'm searching match commands on a juniper firewall

Comment: @kbirds30 you can just add the quotes if you need them to be part of the string. See edit.

Comment: cool i got it with s = ' "({})" '.format('|'.join(my_list))  thanks a ton was killing me

Comment: @kbirds30 looking at your history it looks like you never mark correct answers. You should do that when an answer works for you. It makes it more likely people will help you in the future and will earn you some rep.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
hostman = "("+"|".join(my_list)+")"
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
'(3.3.3.3|2.2.2.3|2.2.2.2)'
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply i got it using s = ' "({})" '.format('|'.join(my_list))